# recursive variadic template function call "loses" pointer on second argument type

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, overloading, variadic-templates

I've got a function (GetArg**s**) using a variadic template that sorts through it's arguments (each a pointer), sending each to another function (GetArg) that has been overloaded for each type (at the moment int & float). The overloaded funtions for each type then set the value at the pointer.

It compiles fine, and when I call the function with however many arguments of a single type it runs fine. However if I use the two types (float & int), it will run fine until the first occurrence of the second type, crashing because (from what I can tell) the pointer address is null (0x0 in debugger).

Here are my function definitions(declared in namespace included in main):

namespace.h

```
int GetArg(int iStackPos,int *i);
int GetArg(int iStackPos,float *f);

template<typename tFirst> int GetArgs(tFirst first)
    {
        GetArg(-1,first);
    }

template<typename tFirst, typename... tRest> int GetArgs(tFirst first, tRest... rest)
    {
        int iStackPos = ((sizeof...(rest) + 1) * -1);


        GetArg(iStackPos,first);
        GetArgs((rest)...);

        return 0;
    }
```

namespace.cpp

```
int GetArg(int iStackPos,int *i)
    {
        *i = 1;
    }

int GetArg(int iStackPos,float *f)
    {
        *f = 2.5;
    }
```

call to get args in main:

would run fine:

```
int *i1;
float *f1;

namespace::GetArgs(f1,f1,f1,f1); //no use of int
```

would crash:

```
int *i1;
float *f1;

namespace::GetArgs(f1,i1,f1); //use of int
```

The same is true when int comes first and float after.
The null pointer happens in the recursive GetArgs() call, and the crash occurs because the overloaded int GetArg() tries to write to that.
The iStackPos is used as position on lua stack, as this is meant to be a wrapper to get arguments from lua. However I've replaced lua code with just assigning int *1*, float *2.5*, as the lua code wasn't the issue.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Can you create  a [MCVE] that exhibits the crash?

Comment: You pass uninitialized pointers to your function and then dereference them `*i = 1`. Where do you expect 1 to be stored?

Comment: Following @n.m.'s point, try `GetArgs(&f1, &i1, &f1);`

Comment: it works if the pointers point to allocated memory: http://ideone.com/aOIuwV

Comment: @YamMarcovic Maybe. I don't read minds (not for free at any rate).

Comment: @n.m. Well this is embarrassing. Yep I just initialized the pointers using `int *i1 = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
 float *f1 = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));` And it works. However when they where uninitialized, the first passed was being being "auto" initialized, I've just confirmed this again. Any idea why?

Comment: @Mouse'nKeyboard Undefined Behavior is Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already suggested, you're passing uninitialized memory into your function. That produces undefined behavior.

Also, you're not returning anything in the `GetArg` functions and the first `GetArgs`. This can get you into trouble as well.

And your combining size_t and int when calculating iStackPos.

Comment: Well, you're passing the ***address*** of uninitialized memory.

Comment: @nicomp Ha! Well, the code is passing uninitialized addresses to memory that may or may not be uninitialized. scnr ;-)